# Are struct fields not mandatory?

Tags: go, struct

I am learning Go, and came into something like:

```
type Something struct {
someField         String
}
```

That then is initialized as: `Something{}`

It was my understanding that we needed to initialize struct with the fields inside of it, but this is compiling and working, so can anybody explain me why this works?

Comment: The elements are optional. You may use keyed items to list some or all, or you may list just the values for the fields, in which case you have to list all. See [Spec: Compsite literals](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Composite_literals).

Comment: If value for a property is omitted, that property will have a [zero value](https://go.dev/tour/basics/12), appropriate for the type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go does not have the notion of undefined. Every data type has a *zero value*.

- https://dave.cheney.net/2013/01/19/what-is-the-zero-value-and-why-is-it-useful
- https://go.dev/tour/basics/12

Any variable/field/property that is not explicitly initialized is initialized by default with the zero value of its data types.

Whether or not that's a good thing is arguable[1], but it is the Go Way™.

[1] For instance, if I'm measuring voltage, a measurement of zero volts is different than not getting a voltage measurement at all. Or if I'm tabulating survey responses, no response is different than a response of "unknown"/"don't know"/"other".